# Replace an embed or iframe youtube video by an tumbnail + link to vídeo

Tags: javascript, replace, youtube, embed, thumbnails

I need an javascript that can be placed on header that recognizes an youtube embed or iframe player and replaces it by a tumbnail linked to the vídeo on youtube.

The script should identifies an code like this ones:

```
<object width="560" height="340"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/J4oJWUJpbLY?fs=1&amp;hl=pt_BR&amp;hd=1&amp;color1=0x5d1719&amp;color2=0xcd311b"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/J4oJWUJpbLY?fs=1&amp;hl=pt_BR&amp;hd=1&amp;color1=0x5d1719&amp;color2=0xcd311b" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="560" height="340"></embed></object>

<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="560" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/J4oJWUJpbLY?hd=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

And replace by it:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1VCUF2xqKk" target="_blank"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/n1VCUF2xqKk/default.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Look that the variable is the video ID.

It is possible?

**UPDATE** [Code whith big thumbs and play icon)

```
//FUNC OBJECT
function changeobj() {
    objs = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
    for (i in objs) {
        for (o in objs[i].children) {
            if (objs[i].children[o].getAttribute && objs[i].children[o].getAttribute('name') == 'movie') {
                    vidid = objs[i].children[o].getAttribute('value').split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
                    linkurl = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+vidid;
                    bgurl = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidid+'/0.jpg';
                    imgurl = 'playsh.png';
                    link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.setAttribute('href',linkurl);
                    link.setAttribute('target','_blank');
                    link.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+bgurl+')';
                    link.className += "youvid";
                    img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.src = imgurl;
                    link.appendChild(img);
                    objs[i].innerHTML = '';
                    objs[i].appendChild(link);
                }
            }
        }
    }

//FUNC IFRAME
function changeiframe() {
    objs = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (i in objs) {
            if (objs[i].src) {
            vidid = objs[i].src.split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
            linkurl = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+vidid;
            bgurl = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidid+'/0.jpg';
            imgurl = 'playsh.png';
            link = document.createElement('a');
            link.setAttribute('href',linkurl);
            link.setAttribute('target','_blank');
            link.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+bgurl+')';
            link.className += "youvid";
            img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = imgurl;
            link.appendChild(img);
            objs[i].outerHTML = link.outerHTML;
            }
        }
    }


window.onload = function () {
    changeobj();
    changeiframe();
    }
```

The CSS:

```
.youvid {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background-position: center;
}
```

One bug still remais, the changeiframe function only replaces the odd ones (1st, 3rd, 5th...).

Comment: Are you controlling how the videos are initially displayed?  You could use oEmbed to easily get a thumbnail generated and manipulate it like that without having to load the iFrame and objects then replace them.  Example here http://levelonestudiosatx.com/media/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with. It has only been tested in Google Chrome.

```
function changeobj() {
    objs = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
    for (i in objs) {
        for (o in objs[i].children) {
            if (objs[i].children[o].getAttribute('name') == 'movie') {
                    vidid = objs[i].children[o].getAttribute('value').split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
                    linkurl = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+vidid;
                    imgurl = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidid+'/default.jpg';
                    link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.setAttribute('href',linkurl);
                    link.setAttribute('target','_blank');
                    img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.src = imgurl;
                    link.appendChild(img);
                    objs[i].innerHTML = '';
                    objs[i].appendChild(link);
                }
            }
        }
    }

function changeiframe() {
    objs = document.getElementsByClassName('youtube-player');
    for (i in objs) {
        console.log(objs[i]);
        vidid = objs[i].src.split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
        linkurl = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+vidid;
        imgurl = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidid+'/default.jpg';
        link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href',linkurl);
        link.setAttribute('target','_blank');
        img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = imgurl;
        link.appendChild(img);
        objs[i].outerHTML = link.outerHTML;
        }
    }

window.onload = function () {
    changeobj();
    changeiframe();
    }
```

Yes, I know. There is a bug in it. That's why it won't finish. I'm working on it.

**EDIT:**

I fixed the original bugs:

```
function changeobj() {
    objs = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
    for (i in objs) {
        for (o in objs[i].children) {
            if (objs[i].children[o].getAttribute && objs[i].children[o].getAttribute('name') == 'movie') {
                    vidid = objs[i].children[o].getAttribute('value').split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
                    linkurl = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+vidid;
                    imgurl = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidid+'/default.jpg';
                    link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.setAttribute('href',linkurl);
                    link.setAttribute('target','_blank');
                    img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.src = imgurl;
                    link.appendChild(img);
                    objs[i].innerHTML = '';
                    objs[i].appendChild(link);
                }
            }
        }
    }

function changeiframe() {
    objs = document.getElementsByClassName('youtube-player');
    for (i in objs) {
            if (objs[i].src) {
            vidid = objs[i].src.split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
            linkurl = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+vidid;
            imgurl = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidid+'/default.jpg';
            link = document.createElement('a');
            link.setAttribute('href',linkurl);
            link.setAttribute('target','_blank');
            img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = imgurl;
            link.appendChild(img);
            objs[i].outerHTML = link.outerHTML;
            }
        }
    }

window.onload = function () {
    changeobj();
    changeiframe();
    }
```

There is another bug that won't load any 4th movie, but I'm sure this should give you enough to make your own version.

**EDIT:**
@evel - If you want to put a play button, you can put something like this into your CSS:

```
.YOUTUBE_VID {
background-image: play.png;
background-repeat: none;
background-postion: center;
}
```

And than add it the class to the link:

```
link.className += " .YOUTUBE_VID";
```

**EDIT:**
Instead of using the for loop, I'm looping the function. This seems to be working:

```
function changeiframe() {
    objs = document.getElementsByClassName('youtube-player');
        if (!objs[0]){return false;};
        if (objs[0]) {
        vidid = objs[0].src.split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
        linkurl = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+vidid;
        imgurl = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidid+'/default.jpg';
        link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href',linkurl);
        link.setAttribute('target','_blank');
        img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = imgurl;
        link.appendChild(img);
        objs[0].outerHTML = link.outerHTML;
        }
        changeiframe();
    }
```

Comment: Great works fine,I dont understand almost nothing about javascript

Comment: Eric your code is great, is possible to put a play button png over the thumbnails and make it compatible whith the big thumb to?

Comment: I added the play button, but I don't know what u mean by the big thumb. If you don't understand javascipt you should take a tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: But if i put the play button as a background it wont be placed behind the Imagen?

I noticed that our "changeobj()" function is actually working well it load many movies as i need. otherwise the "changeiframe();" only works on first movie. If you make it whrite on tag to like (document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');)? Maybe it can work like the obj function no?

Comment: I manage to put the big thumb and the play icon, but could not fix the cangeiframe funcion.

Its actualy load many movies but only replace the odd ones (1st, 3rd, 5th...)

I put the code on edit for you see.

Comment: @Evel - I changed the for to a loop in the function.