# Android - webview, disable or replace youtube videos

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview, youtube-api

I'd like to disable Youtube embedded videos on a WebView, preferably replace them with a link to the Youtube page (that will open the browser picker when clicked)...

This is my (quite generic) webview :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_parodia);

    BlogView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.blogview);
    BlogView.setWebViewClient(new CustomClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = BlogView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    BlogView.loadUrl("http://test.blogspot.com/?m=1");
}
```

**EDIT:** something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703072/replace-an-embed-or-iframe-youtube-video-by-an-tumbnail-link-to-video) is what i'm looking for, any help on how implement it on the android webview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        // Replace youtube vids
        var ytprefix = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/";

        if(src.indexOf(ytprefix) != -1) {
            replaceYT(this, src.substring(ytprefix.length));
        }
    });

    $('object').each(function() {
        var srcel = $('param[name="src"]', this);
        var src = $(srcel).attr('value');
        // Replace youtube vids
        var ytprefix = "http://www.youtube.com/v/";
        if(src.indexOf(ytprefix) != -1) {
            replaceYT(this, src.substring(ytprefix.length));
        }
    });
});

function replaceYT(el, code) {
    if(code.indexOf("/") != -1) {
        code = code.substring(0, code.indexOf("/"));
    }
    if(code.indexOf("?") != -1) {
        code = code.substring(0, code.indexOf("?"));
    }
    var atag = $("<a href='vnd.youtube:" + code +"'><img class='youtubeimg' src='file:///android_asset/youtube-play-button.png' style='background:url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + code + "/0.jpg)'/></a>");
    $(el).replaceWith(atag);
}
```

Just load in jquery and this script. This will replace youtube iframes and object tags with a screenshot from the video and a link to youtube. Tested on a SE Xperia X10 & Nexus 7.

Set up your webview to handle youtube like this:
    WebViewClient mWebClient = new WebViewClient() {

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("http://www.youtube.com") || url.startsWith("vnd.youtube")){
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};
```

Comment: The "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" part helped me force loading youtube videos into android builtin youtube app. Upvote for that.